# HTML text in ionic list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have following list:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in productlistitems">
       {{ item.name }}!
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

item.name is with HTML tags, but they appear as plain text.

How can I achieve that the HTML code gets "executed"?

Comment: Check your console you have an error it stopped processing the page (most likely)

Comment: There is no error in the console.

Comment: answer below is likely correct I overlooked the part about it being HTML.  Believe if it's just a string literal then $sce isn't necessary but if the HTML comes from a service or otherwise isn't a literal the $sce is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to render HTML, use the "ng-bind-html" directive like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div>
```

In your controller, you need to "trust" the data using the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#!) service like this:

```
$scope.item.name = $sce.trustAsHtml("your HTML here");
```

Comment: But I use ng-repeat and can't set this for every item? Or am I stupid now.. I'm setting the items like this in app.js: $scope.productlistitems = currentProducts;

Comment: The link I provided to the $sce service has an example using ng-repeat. I'll try to edit my answer soon.

Comment: I can give you a better answer if you show what the HTML you're trying to render looks like.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the link. Perfect. The example behind the link was great now it works.Thanks.